# Linkedin OAuth 1.0 no longer posting to company wall

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a [legacy] PHP app that is using an old integration to Linkedin (Also using legacy Oauth 1.0a) to post to our users personal, and company wall.

Recently (End of July) we started receiving 500 errors when posting to user's company walls. If the user to chose to post to their personal walls the requests post just fine, it's only the company walls that reject the postings.

The users are admins of the walls (We provide a list of walls the users are admins of that we have previously fetched, and are renewed every time a user wants to post). In the even of the user posting both to their personal wall and company wall at the same time, the personal one succeeds while the company one fails.

I did a quick test using Oauth 2.0 and posting the same data, and it posted just fine.
Anydoby knows what could be the problem, or if Linkedin made any change in their API? According to their documentation, even if use of Oauth 1.0 is not encouraged and the API documentation is not available anymore the service is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the homepage of https://developer.linkedin.com/ it states:

> Effective May 18th, 2018, our Company Pages API will no longer work
>   with OAuth 1.0. We recommend all apps switchover OAuth 2.0
>   authentication before then.

So I'd suggest you switch to OAuth 2.0 to maintain your functionality